# Unable to connect my Google Colab to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, google-colaboratory

> ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user
> 'rushiikeshshinde'@'34.32.239.194' (using password: YES)
> site:stackoverflow.com

What to do? I'm unable to connect My Google Colab to MySQL. Help it out.
Here I tried to connect through user ID & Password

Comment: sql server of any kind are not directly reachable from outside, so you must check the confuguration and search for `mysql reach from lan`